# 関数の引数内で実行される関数？？

Tags: javascript, reactjs

下記のコードの意味がよく分からないです。この `strs` は一体どこから来たのでしょうか？

```
setStreams(strs => {
  strs[streamId].removed = true
  return { ...strs }
})
```

これステートのStreamsを呼び出して渡しているんですね。

#### 参照

https://github.com/yassun-youtube/nextjs-agora-sample/blob/master/pages/index.js#L89

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`useState`](https://ja.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)の仕様

> 関数は前回の state の値を受け取り

です(、という以外に答えようが無い気がします...)。

どこから来たか、というと React フレームワークから渡された、という回答になるでしょうか。

Answer (score 3):

[`=>`はアロー関数式](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)と呼ばれ、関数オブジェクトを構築します。一旦、変数に格納した場合

```
var lambda = strs => {
  strs[streamId].removed = true
  return { ...strs }
};
setStreams(lambda);
```

であり、[function関数式](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function)を使って書くと

```
var lambda = function (strs) {
  strs[streamId].removed = true
  return { ...strs }
};
setStreams(lambda);
```

概ねこのような意味になります。

> この `strs` は一体どこから来たのでしょうか？

上記から分かると思いますが、`strs`はどこかから来たのではなく、関数の仮引数です。

Answer (score 0):

JavaScriptでは関数もオブジェクトです。
で、その関数`SetStreams`は引数として関数オブジェクトをとっているわけですね。

```
setStreams(func);
```

この引数`func`として、提示のコードでは「アロー関数式」を渡しています。
`strs`はアロー関数式の引数です。
アロー関数式について下記を参照して学んでみてください。

[アロー関数式 - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)